# Where did they shoot the scenes in Un Flic at the railway station and the crossing immediately before?

Tags: film-location, un-flic

In *Un Flic* (1972), where did they shoot the scenes at the railway station, where the robbers arrive from St-Jean-de-Monts, I guess it's in Challans? And immediately before that, they come by a railway crossing with the arriving train. One can see traffic signs pointing to La Roche-sur-Yon and St-Jean-de-Monts, but if it was in Challans as well the directions would not make sense, they must have shot that at some other place?!

Comment: idk the movie or the locations, but IMDB lists a few - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067900/locations?ref_=tt_dt_loc

Comment: Thank you for that hint, so it is Challans. But the traffic signs still are confusing me. They must have shot the crossing in the wrong direction (view to north).

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me in the least. I work in the industry & using *LocX* for *realPlaceY* is commonplace. Shoot facing whichever way looks best, or with more choice, which is best for the light. 'No-one will ever notice' ..unless you live there ;) Only this week I watched a car chase in a loc I know well; as they sped off around the corner I muttered, "It's no good going that way, there's no exit" They were driving towards the new Eastenders backlot, which blocked the old entrance at Elstree. Next cut they were half a mile away...